# .Net Regular Expression Currency

Tags: c#, .net, regex, vb.net

I am trying to find the currency in strings like "NTE $22,539,420.00"

I tried to use several regular expressions including `^\s*[\+-]?\s?\$?\s?(\d*\.?\d{2}?){1}$` but none of them seem to work. Does anyone have any suggestions or reasons why the above would not work.

Thanks,
Jim

Comment: So you want the first three characters? Are the strings each on separate lines?

Comment: Because your expression doesn't accept letters (e.g. NTE) in the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are matching the beginning of the string by using ^, and the beginning of your string does not start with any whitespace. You are also not taking into consideration the ',' characters.

Try this \s*[+-]?\s?\$?\s?((\d{1,3},?)+.?\d{2}?)

Comment: You might want to escape the decimal place or any character would match in that position.

Comment: any suggestions for currency that does not have decimal places?

Comment: @Jim - in my testing, this already works for values without a decimal portion. The answer has been updated to fix the '.' vs '\.' problem.

Comment: @nerdfury Weird the value I am testing with now is below and it does not seem to find the match." $18,508,715 Base Period and 4 Option Periods"

Comment: That is because the expression says that the number should be at the end of the string ($). I removed the $ from above, if you test it now, it will work. I left the $ before because the first example did have the money at the end of the string, and I assumed that was the pattern you were looking for. I updated my answer with the fix.

Answer (score 6):

Could you just dump all the formatting (except for the decimal) like so?

```
string money = "NTE $22,539,420.00";
string scrubbed = Regex.Replace(money, @"[^0-9\.]", string.Empty);
```

At this point, scrubbed contains `22539420.00`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

> ^[^\d]+(?:\d{1,3}[.,])+\d{2}$

Answer (score 0):

The first part of the regex matches the start of the string, followed by zero or more spaces, followed possibly by a sign, followed possibly by a '$'...  and then some digits.  Nowhere is there any accommodation for the "NTE" part of your string.  Also, I don't see any accommodation for the commas in your currency format.

Matching floating point can be a bit tricky.  Don't forget about possibilities such as $.02.

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled upon this old post...

Use `\p{Sc}` as suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14169820/regular-expression-to-match-all-currency-symbols/).