# Regular expression to match ALL currency symbols?

Tags: regex, r

Is there a regular expresion that will match ALL currency symbols (not just $) as they appear in HTML?  I am trying to extract all occurrences of money amounts from an html page.  Thanks!

Comment: What about "zk". Is that a currency symbol?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currency_sign

Comment: Be careful with [Cape Verdean Escudos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escudo) as well as [Polish groshes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groschen) - you might get a few false positives.

Comment: @Jan: or USD, CAD, AUD, ... for that matter.

Comment: @muistooshort yeah, CAD could be a problem... especially when vending Computer-Assisted Design software in Canada.

Comment: @Jan: USD could also be a problem if the University of San Diego is involved.

Comment: Note that "ZK" are not just zorkmids. They are [Zambian Kwachas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zambian_kwacha) as well.

Comment: Also, old-style cents could be a problem as far as old-style programming languages go.

Comment: Downvote - not a clear example of what 'ALL currency symbols' are.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`\p{Sc}` seems to be the [magic incantation](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/pcresyntax/) you are looking for.

Comment: Does an equivalent exist for this in JavaScript? Looks like I'm forced to use the actual currency symbols.

Comment: awesome ! how did you find that ? :)

Comment: What currency is that, @VijenderKumar?

Answer (score 1):

I converted [all of currency symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currency_symbol) to Unicode and If you want to check it manually, I suggest you to use this code:

```
[\u00a4\u060b\u0e3f\u002f\u002e\u20bf\u20b5\u00a2\u20a1\u0024\u0434\u0435\u043d\u0438\u043d\u0024\u20ab\u20ac\u0192\u002c\u20b2\u20b4\u20ad\u010d\u043b\u0432\u20ba\u20a5\u20a6\u0024\u20b1\u00a3\u17db\u20bd\u20b9\u20a8\u20aa\u09f3\u20ae\u20a9\u00a5\u0142\u20b3\u20a2\u20b0\u20bb\u20af\u20a0\u20a4\u2133\u20a7\u211b\u20b7\u20b6\u09f2\u09f9\u09fb\u07fe\u07ff\u0bf9\u0af1\u0cb0\u0dbb\u0dd4\ua838\u1e2f\u0046\u0061-\u007a\u0041-\u005a\u0030-\u0039 \u2000-\u200f\u2028-\u202f\u0621-\u0628\u062a-\u063a\u0641-\u0642\u0644-\u0648\u064e-\u0651\u0655\u067e\u0686\u0698\u06a9\u06af\u06be\u06cc\u06f0-\u06f9\u0629\u0643\u0649-\u064b\u064d\u06d5\u0660-\u0669\u005c]{1,5}
```

Comment: How is this better than `\p{Sc}`?

Comment: It is good for somebody who do not want use "\p{Sc}".
I said it is manually.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't support PCRE regex property `\p{Sc}`

You need to use equivalent

```js
function getCurrencySymbol(price: string): string {
  const ScRe =
    /[\$\xA2-\xA5\u058F\u060B\u09F2\u09F3\u09FB\u0AF1\u0BF9\u0E3F\u17DB\u20A0-\u20BD\uA838\uFDFC\uFE69\uFF04\uFFE0\uFFE1\uFFE5\uFFE6]/;

  return price.match(ScRe)[0];
}


// returns "£"
getCurrencySymbol("£10");
```